# Spring MVC Dispatcher unable to find controller handler method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-config

I have the weirdest error ever. In my logs it validates I have created a mapping for "TrainingRequest"

018-10-23 21:58:43,900 [main] [INFO ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/TrainingRequest],methods=[GET]}"

But when I try to go the page http://localhost:8080/WEB/TrainingRequest,
I get a page 404, and the logs says the dispatcher is unable to find the mapping. It reads below as

2018-10-23 22:00:17,129 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [DEBUG] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/TrainingRequest]
2018-10-23 22:00:17,132 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [WARN ] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB/TrainingRequest] in DispatcherServlet

http://localhost:8080/WEB/ works properly, so I doubt it is an issue of configuration. However, here are the snippets below. If you think the issue could be file structure, here is my github [link](https://github.com/rjpruitt16/LNU-Project/tree/master/WEB)

WebConfig.Java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.LNUProject.config")
@Slf4j
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // == constants ==
    public static final String RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/view/";
    public static final String RESOLVER_SUFFIX =".jsp";

    // == bean methods
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix(RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(RESOLVER_SUFFIX);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        log.info("registry add properly");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(ViewNames.HOME);
    }
}
```

ConstantsController.java

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class ConstantsController {
    // == handler methods ==
    // http://localhost:8080/WEB/
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        log.info("Home template map");
        return ViewNames.HOME;
    }
}
```

RequestTraining.java

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class RequestTrainingController {

    final String NAME = "TrainingRequest";

    // == handler methods ==
    // http://localhost:8080/WEB/TrainingRequest
    @GetMapping(NAME)
    public String TableView() {
        log.info("Training VIEW being called");
        return NAME;
    }

    @GetMapping(Mappings.HOME + NAME + Mappings.EDIT)
    public String EditTableView() {
        return NAME + Mappings.EDIT;
    }

    @GetMapping(Mappings.HOME + NAME + Mappings.DELETE)
    public String DeleteTableView() {
        return NAME + Mappings.DELETE;

    }

    @GetMapping(Mappings.HOME + NAME + Mappings.ADD)
    public String AddTableView() {
        return NAME + Mappings.ADD;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addViewController` method mapping for `TrainingRequest` is missing

Do something like this

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        log.info("registry add properly");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(ViewNames.HOME);
        registry.addViewController("/TrainingRequest").setViewName("TrainingRequest");
    }
```

Comment: You mean to tell me, I have to explicitly name all controller urls. Is there a better way to register all variables in ViewNames in the addViewControllers methods.